# Having trouble getting Matplotlib to work(?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm following the tutorial video linked here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAwQ-noyB98

I installed Matplotlib, including the other necessary libraries: numpy, dateutil, pytz, pyparsing, and six.

Now, I'm trying the following command(s):

> > > import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> > >
> > > plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8,9,10,11])

I'm expecting some sort of graphic to appear, but nothing happens(?) If I try:

> > > print plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8,9,10,11])

I get [matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x03047510]

So it looks like something is being created, it's just not an image file. Any Idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You've created a graphic of your plot but you haven't told matplotlib to show it yet. Your full code should be something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
plt.show()
```

Matplotlib doesn't plot each graph as you plot it as plotting can be computer intensive, as such it holds off until the user chooses to show them using the `show` method ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.show)).